# PhpSpreadsheet: value is interpreted as number even if the cell format is set to text

Tags: phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I **first** set a cell to be **text**

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( "A1" )->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Then I set the cell value to a string that *may* be interpreted as a number

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( "A1", "10.20" );
```

When I open the Excel file the cell `A1` is actually TEXT but the value is

```
10,2
```

(my Excel has a preference set to use comma as decimal separator).

So despite the text format and the fact that I also pass a string to `setCellValueByColumnAndRow()` the trailing zero is lost and dot converted to comma.

I want the cell to be `10.20`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I need to use

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit( "A1", $value, PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING );
```